# Can't setup useReducer with React/TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-reducer

I'm learning TypeScript. I'm trying to set up `useReducer` but I'm having a hard time doing it. The fix is probably fairly simple, so sorry for that. This is my `App.tsx`:

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import { StartPage } from "./components/StartPage";
import { QuestionsPage } from "./components/QuestionsPage";

type State = {};

type Action = {};

const initialState = {
  hasStarted: false // one of the states I'm going to need
};

const reducer = (state: State, action: Action) => {};

export const App = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState); // * error here

  return (
    <>
      <StartPage dispatch={dispatch}/>
      <QuestionsPage />
    </>
  );
};
```

(Perhaps) good to know: I'm trying to set it up in a basic way first, but later I want to conditionally render either `StartPage.tsx` or `QuestionsPage.tsx` based on whether `hasStarted` is `true` or `false` (which I'm going to set up in `StartPage.tsx`.

I'm getting the following error here (see `*` in code snippet above):

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 5, '(reducer: ReducerWithoutAction, initializerArg: any, initializer?: undefined): [any, DispatchWithoutAction]', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(state: State, action: Action) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducerWithoutAction'.
> Overload 2 of 5, '(reducer: (state: State, action: Action) => void, initialState: never, initializer?: undefined): [never, Dispatch]', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an error in Typescript because you are not returning any state inside the **reducer** function. This would do the fix:

```
const reducer = (state: State, action: Action) => {
 //...logic for updating the state
 return state; 
};
```